# Laravel 5: Return all fields except created_at and udpated_at

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have the next code:

```
$list = Prov::all();
```

I need to return all fields except "created_at", "updated_at" and "state" in Laravel using Eloquent.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 4):

The `all` method returns all rows with all of their properties. If you want to hide some fields for json simply add them to protected `$hidden` array in your model.

```
protected $hidden = ["created_at", "updated_at"];
```

But if you want to hide them from php eloquent model, you may add method to this model which unsets given properties from model. And then loop through your collection and fire custom method on every item or use collection mapping:

```
$modified_items = Prov::all()->map(function($item){
    return $item->myUnsettingMethod();
})
```

Of course you can still make direct query:

```
$provs = DB::table('provs')->select('some_column', 'another_column as ac')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass an array of field names to `all()` or you can override the `all()` function in your model and pass your field names as default values on the $columns array parameter like:

```
 /**
 * Get all of the models from the database. Overrided from Laravel 5.1.27
 *
 * @param  array|mixed  $columns // this is where you override instead of '*'
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|static[]
 */
public static function all($columns = ['id','name','description'])
{
    $columns = is_array($columns) ? $columns : func_get_args();

    $instance = new static;

    return $instance->newQuery()->get($columns);
}
```

Other way to solve this is creating a scope in your Model and using it here like `Prov::myFields()->get()`